# Can I tile my shower in stages on different days?

Tags: shower, tile

I am trying to decide if I want to tile my shower myself. Can I tile in sections on different days? Say if I can only get a few walls done and have to stop, is that ok? I have built an L shaped shower with a bench seat in the short leg. I am pretty confident I can do a good job but it may take me longer than it would a more experienced tile setter. I don't want to compromise the integrity of the shower. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the tile at different times is fine but when you grout the spaces you want to try and do these at the same time or you may see some shade differences.